# ... WHERE ['ID_two','ID_four'] COINTAINS_AT_LEAST_ONE_ID_FROM ['ID_one','ID_two','ID_three']

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.0

I would like to have an SQL query where I check if one ID (of an array with ID's) matches at least one ID out of an array of other ID's. **The ID's are stings.**

It should be like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ids COINTAINS_AT_LEAST_ONE_ID_FROM ['ID_one','ID_two','ID_three']
```

table1.ids contains also an array with IDs. For example, let's say ['ID_two','ID_four']

I saw several solutions but I am using an **old PostgreSQL Version (8.0.2 on Redshift)** and nothing worked so far.

Do you know a solution? :)

Greetings

Comment: The [overlap operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-array.html) was added in v8.2

Comment: can you use `unnest`?

Comment: @SalmanA : unnest is not available in 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly solution (if you're desperate), it should work on 8.0 :

First create the t10 table that you'll use as an iterator (adjust it to your maximum array size):

```
CREATE TABLE T10 (ID INTEGER);

INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (8);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO T10 VALUES (10);
```

Then here is the test table :

```
create table table1 (
    ids text[]
);

insert into table1 (ids) values (ARRAY['ID_two','ID_four']);

select * from table1;

       ids        
------------------
 {ID_two,ID_four}
```

Then, the query, that use T10 to iterate over all members of your arrays :

```
\set myids ARRAY['''ID_one''','''ID_two''','''ID_three''']

select *
  from (
     select ids[iter.pos] as ids
     from table1
     join (select id as pos from t10) iter
     on iter.pos <= array_length(ids,1)) as A
  join (
     select (:myids)[iter.pos] as ids
     from (select id as pos from t10) iter
     where iter.pos <= array_length(:myids,1)) as B
  on a.ids = b.ids;

  ids   |  ids
--------+--------
 ID_two | ID_two
```